# c# Win Form - Unable to change text of an "input" in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using `Webbrowser` control to login this [page](https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login) by using the following code

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login"));
```

Now for changing the password I am using the below code which isn't working.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass").InnerText = "ABC123";
//OR
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass").SetAttribute("type", "text");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass").SetAttribute("text", "ABC123");
//OR
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass").SetAttribute("text", "ABC123");
//OR
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass").SetAttribute("value", "ABC123");
```

Can anyone tell me how to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to wait that the page is **fully loaded**:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += OnDocumentLoaded;
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login"));
```

Now you can set `value` attribute (which contains the content of `<input>` elements):

```
private void OnDocumentLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass")
        .SetAttribute("value", "the_password");    
}
```

As alternative you may also *send* keystrokes:

```
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass").Focus();
    SendKeys.Send("the_password");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i have already taken the measure like waiting till it fully loads and the code with setting "value" attribute doesn't work too and i have already tried sending keys which didnt work.

Comment: First  be sure that ID you're using is the right one and also that document is loaded (URL in your example does not work at all)

Comment: please can you check if i am making any mistake because i have checked it and it seems to be ok and i am manually triggering the code on button click after i see that it has loaded completely.

Comment: Is URL https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login correct? I can't even navigate there in my browser

Comment: yes it is, you might have to use VPN if it is causing problem because it is a ".in" site.

Comment: Too troublesome...If you step in debug inside that code: 1) what do you get with `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass")` (consider to log that value instead of really stepping in debug, if there is something wrong with timing then problem will disappear in debug)

Comment: if i use the below code       webBrowser1.Document.Forms["loginform"].Document.GetElementById("user_pass").SetAttribute("value", GST_Password);
                        object obj = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass").GetAttribute("value"); then in debug it shows that the object obj has ABC123 value which actually is not displayed on the screen.

Comment: Why `webBrowser1.Document.Forms["loginform"].Document.GetElementB‌​yId("user_pass")`? (I mean...get the form then go back to the `Document` to get the ID?) What's the type of `#user_pass` element? If it's not an `<input>` then you can set the `value` attribute but it has no _meaning_ for it. You might post the (cleaned) HTML content of that page.

Comment: ahhhh SHEET, my bad. Now it is working fine. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The field you are trying to set is a password type field and not text type field. This is not a good way to do it but I may suggest you do it it this way:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass").SetAttribute("value", "ABC123");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the code with setting "value" attribute doesn't work too.